# OProfile failed to generate callgraph

Tags: profiling, callstack, call-graph, oprofile

I'm trying to generate a callgraph using oprofile and for some reason it fails.
I'm using the below command to config it:

```
opcontrol --shutdown
opcontrol --reset
opcontrol --no-vmlinux
opcontrol --separate=library
opcontrol --event=default
opcontrol --callgraph=20
opcontrol --status
```

Here I get:

```
Daemon not running
Event 0: CPU_CLK_UNHALTED:100000:0:1:1
Separate options: library
vmlinux file: none
Image filter: none
Call-graph depth: 20
Buffer size: 10000000
CPU buffer watershed: 2560000
CPU buffer size: 160000
```

Then when trying to generate callgraph (for example using `opreport pdpd -l --callgraph -o profile_pdp.txt`)

I get:

```
30        0.7659  libpthread-2.5.so        pthread_mutex_lock
30       100.000  libpthread-2.5.so        pthread_mutex_lock [self]
```

My linux kernel version is 2.6.18

I do get the following error when running opreport (don't know if relevant):

```
opreport: /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6: no version information available (required by opreport)
```

Any idea why I can't get the full callgraph?

Comment: Found the issue, it was working with a 64bit kernel while debugging 32bit exe, don't know whay it is an issue for oprofile

Answer (score 1):

Found the issue, it was working with a 64bit kernel while debugging 32bit exe, don't know whay it is an issue for oprofile.